# Specific name of # (hash) as in preprocessor directives like #include, #define, etc

Tags: c

What does it exactly convey?
Also, it is used in USSD codes in phones. Do they mean the same thing?
Is there any particular name/group for the symbol '#'?For example !, ||, && belong to logical operators, >, <, ==, etc., belong to relational operators.

Comment: You've already given the answer in the title: The `#` symbol is called hash mark (among other names) and in C, it introduces preprocessor directives, which you could consider a group. What's the point of your question?

Comment: "*it is used in USSD codes in phones. Do they mean the same thing*". Why would they? They are totally different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard has no formal name for `#`. It is used as the start of a pre-processing directive or as part of the `#` or `##` pre-processor operators.

Informally it is often just called "hash" or "sharp". The # operator is often informally called "stringification" or such. The ## operator is informally called token concatenation operator.

> Is there any particular name/group for the symbol '#'?

No.

> For example !, ||, && belong to logical operators

No. `!` formally belongs to the group of *unary operators*, which apart from being unary prefix have nothing in common. Grouping of operators in C is mostly relevant for determining operator precedence and associativity, rather than functionality.

> ...>, <, ==, etc., belong to relational operators

No. `>` and `<` are relational operators. `==` belongs to the group of equality operators. Relational operators have higher precedence than equality operators.

> Also, it is used in USSD codes in phones. Do they mean the same thing?

Why would it? It's also used by Twitter, or for naming the C# language, or numerous other things completely unrelated to C programming...